# Android APK download of my app doesn't work, Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, configuration, crash

**Short version:**
Xamarin.Android app crashes with prod config but not with test config. It works on both my phones, but not on customers (and it works on customers if I USB-debug the same app from my computer first).

**Long version:**
I've developed a Xamarin.Android app for a customer, which has been working fine until now. There's one Test-version and one Prod-version of the App, the APK is published to a site, and the link is sent to my customer. The test version has always been working fine, but when I send the link of the Prod-version to my customer, the app crashes after about half a second when trying to start it. The test-version works as it should, and the only difference is some configurations and app manifest changes (like package name, app icon, etc).

**The wierdest thing:** I've got access to the customers phone and I USB-debugged the prod-version of the app directly from my computer, and then everything works fine. And after I've done that, the app from the same link as before works without crashes. **Could "enable developer mode" or "enable USB-debugging" make the difference here? (why would that make the app crash before it launches?)** . And even if I disable developer mode again, the link still gives me a working app. But I can't ofcourse first usb-debug every phone that will use the app before they will be able to use it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is on `logcat` when the app crashes?

Comment: The app does not crash if I build it from a computer, only if I use the link to download it. Is there any crash logs in the phone when I don't use USB-debugging to run it?

Comment: Yes, via `logcat`... able debugging on the device so you can connect `adb` (`adb logcat`), but install the prod version and monitor logcat output for errors (they will be there) when you start it and it crashes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: The problem was "Android Options -> Use shared runtime" was set for some reason. It should be unchecked